# Pass arguments from fragment to viewmodel function

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

Can you tell me if my approach is right? It works but I don't know if it's correct architecture. I read somewhere that we should avoid calling viewmodel function on function responsible for creating fragments/activities mainly because of screen orientation change which recall network request but I really need to pass arguments from one viewmodel to another one. Important thing is I'm using Dagger Hilt dependency injection so creating factory for each viewmodel isn't reasonable?

Assume I have RecyclerView of items and on click I want to launch new fragment with details - common thing. Because logic of these screens is complicated I decided to separate single viewmodel to two - one for list fragment, one for details fragment.

[image: items structure]

`ItemsFragment` has listener and launches details fragment using following code:

```
    fun onItemSelected(item: Item) {
        val args = Bundle().apply {
            putInt(KEY_ITEM_ID, item.id)
        }
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_detailsFragment, args)
    }
```

Then in `ItemDetailsFragment` class in `onViewCreated` function I receive passed argument, saves it in `ItemDetailsViewModel` `itemId` variable and then launch `requestItemDetails()` function to make api call which result is saved to LiveData which is observed by `ItemDetailsFragment`

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //...
        val itemId = arguments?.getInt(KEY_ITEM_ID, -1) ?: -1
        viewModel.itemId = itemId
        viewModel.requestItemDetails()
        //...
    }
```

ItemDetailsViewModel

```
class ItemDetailsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    var itemId: Int = -1

    private val _item = MutableLiveData<Item>()
    val item: LiveData<Item> = _item

    fun requestItemDetails() {
        if (itemId == -1) {
            // return error state
            return
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = repository.getItemDetails(itemId)
            //...
            _item.postValue(response.data)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Good news is that this is what `SavedStateHandle` is for, which automatically receives the arguments as its initial map.

```
@HiltViewModel
class ItemDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val itemId = savedStateHandle.getLiveData(KEY_ITEM_ID)

    val item: LiveData<Item> = itemId.switchMap { itemId ->
        liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext) {
            emit(repository.getItemDetails(itemId).data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you pass arguments from fragment?

Comment: the savedStateHandle is Empty !

Comment: @HussienFahmy it isn't empty if you configure things correctly

Comment: The problem was am using 'by activityViewModels()'

Comment: well in that case you only see whatever is passed to the activity via intent

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Why is it not mentioned in the documentation that SavedStateHandle also handle fragment.arguments?

Comment: @VolodymyrZakharov The key value bundle which you pass during the navigation call can be retrieved in savedStateHandle. Eg: `findNavController().navigate(R.id.destination, Bundle().apply { putString("key", "value") })`

Answer (score 0):

> we should avoid calling viewmodel function on function responsible for creating fragments/activities mainly because of screen orientation change which recall network request

Yes, in your example a request will be executed whenever `ItemDetailsFragment`'s view is created.

Take a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2287) about assisted injection support in Hilt. The point of assisted injection is to pass additional dependencies at object's creation time.

This will allow you to pass `itemId` through the constructor, which then will allow you to access it in `ViewModel`'s `init` block.

```kotlin
class ItemDetailsViewModel @HiltViewModel constructor(
    private val repository: Repository,
    @Assisted private val itemId: Int
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        requestItemDetails()
    }

    private fun requestItemDetails() {
        // Do stuff with itemId.
    }
}
```

This way the network request will be executed just once when `ItemDetailsViewModel` is created.

---

By the time the feature is available you can either try workarounds suggested in the GitHub issue or simulate the `init` block with a flag:

```kotlin
class ItemDetailsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {

    private var isInitialized = false

    fun initialize(itemId: Int) {
        if (isInitialized) return
        isInitialized = true

        requestItemDetails(itemId)
    }

    private fun requestItemDetails(itemId: Int) {
        // Do stuff with itemId.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I just thought about using somekind flag. Meanwhile I realised I wanted to achieve impossible, because I wanted to pass argument to function without passing it... As I understand the part about passing argument in onCreateView is correct? I just need to take care of avoid multiple unnecessary api calls in viewmodel class?

Comment: Generally, that is correct. Although I guess there are some specific use cases where you'd want to reload on configuration change, e.g. downloading a more detailed image for landscape mode. You can treat my suggestion as a [rule of thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb).